# Why these two propositions have different requirements

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, self-learning, exact-sequence

[image]
[image]

Proposition 2.18 is similar to 2.19.

Why we need $N$ flat in 2.19?

What's the difference between 2.18 and 2.19?

Comment: What definition of flatness do you use? Because this is usually taken as the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the difference is left-exactness, i.e. whether the left map is exact. Proposition 2.18 omits the $0 \longrightarrow M'$ map.